# Is it unconventional to override unittest.TestCase's init in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

Whenever a single initialization is required before all the tests (independent) are invoked, and not before each tests, I do so in a separate function outside the test class. I was wondering if it would be possible to override the `__init__` method of `unittest.TestCase` and do the initialization there.

Here's what I usually do:

```
import unittest


basket = {}


def initiate():
    """Update Fruit basket - fruits and their ages."""
    fruits = {2: "Apples",
              4: "Grapes",
              3: "Bananas"}
    basket.update(fruits)


class FruitBasket(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_grapes(self):
        """Any grapes in the basket."""
        self.assertIn("Grapes", basket.values())


    def test_rotten(self):
        """Stinky test."""
        for age in basket.keys():
            self.assertLess(age, 4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    initiate()
    unittest.main()
```

The `initiate()` is independent of the `FruitBasket` test class. This becomes a problem when the module is imported in to others (repeated manual initialization). Is there a better way of achieving this within the same class? I haven't seen the `__init__()` of `TestCase` overridden anywhere before. If it is not OK to do so (adhering to Pythonic style), what must be done? The `setUp()` instance method is inappropriate here, since it is called before each test and not just once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `TestCase.__init__` is used when building the suites and running the test to select the test method to run. In fact when you want to manually create a `TestSuite` to run the tests without using the higher-level interface of test runners you do:

```
import unittest


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        print("One")
    def test_two(self):
        print("Two")


suite = unittest.TestSuite([MyTestCase('test_one'), MyTestCase('test_two')])

suite.run(unittest.TestResult())
```

And *behold*! You are creating a `MyTestCase` instance for *every* test!

Keep in mind that when you use the higher level interface to run the tests, it simply hides the steps to building `TestSuite`s as above.

This already shows that you shouldn't override the `__init__` since it will be called once for every test.

However the `unittest` module provides mechanisms to add fixtures to classes and even modules. See the [Class and Module Fixtures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures) section of the `unittest` documentation.

In particular the [`setUpClass` and `tearDownClass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) do exactly what you want: they are called *once* before and after running the tests of a `TestCase` subclass.

---

Note that `setUpClass` might be called *more* than once. However this would happen only when building `TestSuite`s manually. For example the code:

```
import unittest


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('MyTestCase.setUpClass')
    def test_one(self):
        print("One")
    def test_two(self):
        print("Two")

class MyTestCase2(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('MyTestCase2.setUpClass')
    def test_three(self):
        print('Three')



suite = unittest.TestSuite([MyTestCase('test_one'), MyTestCase2('test_three'), MyTestCase('test_two')])

suite.run(unittest.TestResult())
```

Produces the output:

```
MyTestCase.setUpClass
One
MyTestCase2.setUpClass
Three
MyTestCase.setUpClass
Two
```

The `TestSuite` executes the tests in order. Whenever it sees that the class from which the test is taken changes it calls `tearDownClass` from the "current" class and then calls "setUpClass" for the next class. If you mix the tests of different classes you may see `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` called more than once.

Comment: +1. Remarkable answer! If the suite is creating a `MyTestCase` instance for every test, wouldn't it be *bad* in terms of resources? Does this imply that for accessing two instance methods of the same object, two separate objects are created by the suite? Does this have an advantage over the other?

Comment: @user3058846 The advantage is that the tests are more independent (which is good; you don't want one test to pass only because a an other test, by mistake, did something that somehow hid the error).  Obviously it costs more, but usually not much. If you care for efficiency you put costly setups into per-module or per-class setups (e.g. opening connections to a database etc.)

Answer (score 0):

That is much better achieved using the [`setUpClass` class method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass):

```
class FruitBasket(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.basket = {2: "Apples",
                      4: "Grapes",
                      3: "Bananas"}

    def test_grapes(self):
        """Any grapes in the basket."""
        self.assertIn("Grapes", self.basket.values())

    def test_rotten(self):
        """Stinky test."""
        for age in self.basket.keys():
            self.assertLess(age, 4)
```

Comment: The only problem with setup is that it is run before each test, which is undesirable if the initialization is supposed to run once. Besides, updating a dict or appending to a list must be done once during such initializations (which is not the case in your code).

Comment: +1, Wouldn't it be better to update the dictionary rather than assigning it?

Comment: @user3058846 in this case, the 'global' `basket` is *not* being used (note `self.basket` in the individual tests). There would be no benefit to `self.basket = {}; fruits = {...}; self.basket.update(fruits)`; this just builds two dictionaries instead of one.

Comment: It can not be done by overriding `__init__()` new instance of the test case is created for each test. `setUpClass()` is the way to go.